# IDL (Interface Definition Language) for SignalR and Message Broker

Tags: c#, signalr, idl, messagebroker

**Background**

We want to use SignalR for communicating bidirectionally between a Web-Client and a server written in C#. There is another client written with C# which also needs to support communicating over SignalR with the server. At the same time we are introducing a message broker (RabbitMQ).

**Problem**

We have about 35 persons working on the software and need a way for defining the messages formally. For the message broker we thought about using [ProtoBuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) and had the idea of using the same or similar for SignalR (if possible).

**Question**

Is there any IDL (Interface Definition Language) we can use for SignalR AND the message broker? If not: Is there any way of formally defining the messages in SignalR?